# How to modify the registered event in Libevent?

Tags: c, events, epoll, libevent

I use libevent like this,

```
client->m_event = event_new(listener->m_server->m_server_base, client->m_sockfd, EV_PERSIST, Client::ClientEventCallback, client);
event_add(client->m_event, NULL);
```

But I don't know how to modify the event of m_event, there seems to be no interface to operate in official manual, i tried to do it like this, but it make a core dump.

```
short event = event_get_events(m_event);
event_del(m_event);
event_assign(m_event, m_server->m_server_base, m_sockfd, event | EV_WRITE, Client::ClientEventCallback, this);
event_add(m_event, NULL);
```

core dump ocurs at event_assign, please help me ... how to modify the registed event of the struct event ?

Comment: And I don't want to use bufferevent, beacse i have my own statusmachine implement. is there any good method to solve this except free the old one and event_new the newer one? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that should make you core dump, but I might inquire as to why you're event_assign'ing again anyways just to add in the `EV_WRITE` flag. Correct me if i'm wrong, but since your `event_new` is only specifying `EV_PERSIST`, I don't think it'll ever fire (so why event_add it at that point?) It seems like you should just be doing

```
client->m_event = event_new(listener->m_server->m_server_base, client->m_sockfd, EV_PERSIST | EV_WRITE, Client::ClientEventCallback, client);
```

up top, then when you are ready to write just do

```
event_add(m_event, NULL);
```

and when you're done writing

```
event_del(m_event);
```

Anyways, like I said I wouldn't think what you're doing should be a problem per-say, but if there is some funky behavior that happens when you add an event with only `EV_PERSIST` as the event type and then later del/assign it, the above may solve it. (And it'll be less code / more effecient anyways, so might as well :))